# simplexml patch for allow_url_fopen to be use on simplehtmldom

Tags: php, simplexml

My hosting company has disabled allow_url_fopen & allow_url_include. They recommend that I use cURL instead, then I saw this patch on simplexml

```
$calendar = simplexml_load_file($source); with
if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
$calendar =       simplexml_load_file($source); 
}   
else {    
$ch = curl_init($source);    
curl_setopt  ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
$xml_raw = curl_exec($ch);    
$calendar = simplexml_load_string($xml_raw);  }
```

and it works on my hosting so I was wondering if I could use it on simplehtmldom here is the code I am using

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
include ('phpQuery.php');   
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://www.urlhere.com/');
   ?>
```

Can i use this? If yes what changes should I make, thank you for your help

Edited above code

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 
include ('phpQuery.php'); 

if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {       
$html = file_get_html('http://www.weather.bm/'); }
else{       $ch = curl_init('http://www.weather.bm/');           
curl_setopt  ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);           
$src = curl_exec($ch);           
$html = str_get_html($src, false); 
var_dump($html);  }   

?>

<div id="leftwrapper">
<div id="CurrentConditions">
<h2>Current Conditions</h2>

<div id="current-content">
<div id="elementleft">
<?php
foreach($html->find('div.obElementLeft') as $e)
echo $e->outertext;
?>
</div>
<div id="elementright"><?php 
foreach($html->find('div.obElementRight') as $e)
echo $e->outertext; 
?>
</div></div></div>
<div id="rightwrapper"> 
<div id="TodayForecast">
<h2>24-Hour Forecast</h2>
<?php 
foreach($html->find('.TodaysForecastContainer') as $e)
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML( $e );  
$containers = pq('.TodaysForecastContainerInner', $doc); 
foreach( $containers as $container ) {     
$div = pq('div', $container);      
$div->eq(1)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('thumbnail')->
html( pq( 'img', $div->eq(1))->removeAttr('height')->
removeAttr('width')->removeAttr('alt') ); 
$div->eq(0)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('day')-> 
html( pq( 'u', $div->eq(0) )->html() );           
$div->eq(2)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('description');   }  
print $doc; 
?>

</div><!--end of todayforecast--> 
<div id="bws-foot">Weather data provided in part by the Bermuda Weather
Service</div>     <img id="bws-logo" src="images/bwslogo.jpg" />
<div id="hilo">
<p>Today's Temperature:</p>
<?php
foreach($html->find('div.HiLoContainer') as $e)
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML( $e );  
$containers = pq('div.HiLoContainer', $doc); 
foreach( $containers as $container ) {     $div = pq('div', $container);        
$div->eq(0)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('hi1');  
$div->eq(1)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('lo1'); 
}  print $doc; 
?>
```

### Outlook

find('.SynopsisContainer span') as $e)
   echo $e->innertext . '
';
   ?>

### 4 Day Weather Forecast

foreach($html->find('.FourDayForecastContainer') as $e)

$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML( $e );
   $containers = pq ('.FourDayForecastContainerInner', $doc); 
   foreach( $containers as $container ) {     $div = pq('span', $container);
   $img = pq('img', $container);
   $div->eq(0)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('day')->
   html( pq( 'u', $div->eq(0) )->html() );

$img->eq(0)->removeAttr('style')->removeAttr('height')->
   removeAttr('width')->removeAttr('alt')->addClass('thumbnail')->
   html( pq( 'img', $img->eq(0)) );$imghtml = pq('a', $container)->
   html(); pq($container)->prepend($imghtml); pq('a', $container)->remove();
   $div->eq(1)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('hi');
   $div->eq(3)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('lo'); 
   $div->eq(5)->removeAttr('style')->addClass('description');   }  print $doc; 
   ?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to edit the simple_html_dom source. Its easier to just create your own function that does what the original does. The original (which you can't use because of allow_url_fopen) is:

```
function file_get_html() {
    $dom = new simple_html_dom;
    $args = func_get_args();
    @$dom->load(call_user_func_array('file_get_contents', $args), true);
    if (($error=error_get_last())!==null)
    throw new Exception($error['message']);
    return $dom;
}
```

You can just do this:

```
if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
      $html = file_get_html('http://www.urlhere.com/');
}else{
      $ch = curl_init('http://www.urlhere.com/');    
      curl_setopt  ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
      $src = curl_exec($ch);    
      $html = str_get_html($src, false);
}
```

No need to modify the source, and effectively does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks fermi I use use your code and replaced include('simple_html_dom.php'); include ('phpQuery.php'); in my code  with if(ini_get... and did not change simple_html_dom source but it didn't work only showed blank screen

Comment: Well, add this: `var_dump($html);` and see if anything was received by the CURL code.

Comment: Fermi it still shows blank page i edited my post above with your code

Comment: Well, if you do `var_dump($src);` does it show anything? Did the `curl_exec` call work?

Comment: <head>
 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 
</head><body>

Comment: It didn't show anything i really appreciate your help femi I'll try to fix it further. hopefully your script would work eventually

Comment: Well, that output (the html) looks right, so it appears the curl_exec did the right thing. Ah, I just realized: you have to still use `include('simple_html_dom.php');` as that provides the `str_get_html` function. Put that include statement back in and I think that should fix your issues.

Comment: I did that already still a blank page I also tried to remove phpquery leaving just simplehtmldom but nothing seems to work

Comment: Edit your post and include the ENTIRE source so I can see what might be missing.

Comment: I posted the enitre post thanks Femi simplehtmldom code is unchanged

Comment: And...I see your problem: move the 2 include statements to be the very first thing in the file: they have to come BEFORE `str_get_html`, NOT after, otherwise the function doesn't exist.

Comment: I move the the two includes above same result blank page, I edited the code above, I really appreciate you helping me out with this femi

Comment: femi it did work but it scrape the entire site http://www.rgbdahosting.com/weather/weather.php

Comment: Femi Great news thank you so much for your help it worked I forgot to remove the the var_dump i don't know how to thank you enough I have looking for the solution to this problem for quite sometime now thank you so much

Comment: Alright: simple test to see if the issue is with the curl code: try using just this in a file and see what it does: `<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$ch = curl_init('http://www.weather.bm/');
curl_setopt  ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$src = curl_exec($ch);
$html = str_get_html($src, false);
var_dump($html);`

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the [`data://`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php) stream wrapper that will allow you to use the `file_get_html()` function without altering it.

```
if (!ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    $ch = curl_init($source);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
    $xml_raw = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);   
    $source  = 'data://text/html;base64,'.base64_encode($xml_raw);
}
$html = file_get_html($source);
```

This approach uses the [RFC 2397](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2397.html) data URL scheme which is supported in PHP 5.2.0 and later.

Comment: Thank you also for your post =) I'll keep a note on this also